# Mersenne Prime - why are these two definitions equivalent?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime):

> If $n$ is a composite number then so is $2^n − 1$. ($2^{ab} − 1$ is divisible
>   by both $2^a − 1$ and $2^b − 1$.) This definition is therefore equivalent to
>   a definition as a prime number of the form $M_p = 2^p − 1$ for some prime
>   $p$.

I'm wondering why the definition is equivalent. If $p$ is prime, it doesn't necessarily mean that $2^p-1$ is prime, of course. It does, however, mean from my understanding that by the contrapositive, if $2^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime, but that doesn't help much. So what precisely does the second sentence mean?

Comment: It looks like multiple Wikipedia editors have tried rewriting that last sentence in unsuccessful (perhaps even counterproductive) attempts to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not clear from your extract which definitions are being counted as equivalent. It looks like:

A Mersenne Prime is a prime of the form $2^n-1$

and

A Mersenne Prime is a prime of the form $2^p-1$ with $p$ prime

And the fact that if $n$ is composite, so is $2^n-1$ means that these define the same set of primes.

Comment: Thank you - can you please help me understand why the last sentence you wrote is true? Why does that fact mean that they define the same set of primes? I think that's where I'm getting confused.

Comment: You said it yourself: if $2^n-1$ is prime then $n$ is prime.  So a "prime of the form $2^n-1$" is "a prime of the form $2^n-1$ where $n$ is prime".  Now just change the $n$ to $p$.

Comment: @rb612 you quoted "If n is a composite number then so is 2^n-1". It's equivalent to "If 2^n-1 is a prime, then n is a prime".

Comment: @rb612 $2^n-1$ is composite if $n$ is composite. It can therefore only be prime if $n$ is prime. It is not, however true that $2^p-1$ is prime whenever $p$ is a prime. For example $2^{11}-1=2047=23\times 89$ (note that both factors are $\equiv 1 \bmod 22=2\times 11$). If we are hunting for primes we therefore restrict ourselves to prime exponents, but still have more work to do.

Answer (score 3):

The claim is that the following two are equivalent for each $N$:

1. $N$ is a prime and $N$ can be written as $N=2^n-1$ where $n$ is a natural number.
2. $N$ is a prime and $N$ can be written as $N=2^p-1$ where $p$ is a prime.

Further, they say that because they are equivalent, both can be used as the definition of a *Mersenne prime*.

Proof that they are equivalent:

- Proof that 2 implies 1: Assume 2 is true. Just set $n=p$ in 1. Done.
- Proof that 1 implies 2: Assume 1 is true. $N=2^n-1$ is a prime, so $n$ can't be composite (as shown in your quote). So $n$ is a prime. So $N$ can be written as $2^p-1$ where $p$ is a prime. So 2 is true.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, a Mersenne prime is a Mersenne number, i.e., a number of the form
$$M_n=2^n-1$$
which is itself prime. Thus, in order for $M_n$ to be prime,  $n$ must also be prime. This follows, as for any composite $n$ with factors $a$ and $b$, $n=ab$.

Thus $2^n-1$ can be written as $2^{ab}-1$, which is a binomial number that always has a factor  $(2^a-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the paragraph is trying to say the following for $M_n$

$$
n \textrm{ composite} \Rightarrow M_n  \textrm{ composite}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
M_n \neg  \textrm{ composite} 
\Rightarrow n \neg
 \textrm{ composite}
$$
I.e. is equivalent to
$$
M_n \textrm{ prime} 
\Rightarrow n 
 \textrm{ prime}
$$